# ggplot2 Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 0 provided

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to make this plot in a black and white theme using libraries ggeffects and ggplot2. Here's the data.

x

```
x   predicted   std.error   conf.low    conf.high   group   facet   GDP
-40 7.714371    0.1365895   7.446661    7.982082    -0.72   -11.8   -11.8
-40 7.622457    0.08784414  7.450285    7.794628    -0.72   1.2 1.2
-40 7.530471    0.10260416  7.329371    7.731571    -0.72   14.21   14.21
-40 7.21044 0.12862934  6.958332    7.462549    0.08    -11.8   -11.8
-40 7.125252    0.08246387  6.963625    7.286878    0.08    1.2 1.2
-40 7.039997    0.09995428  6.84409 7.235904    0.08    14.21   14.21
-40 6.706509    0.14263394  6.426952    6.986067    0.88    -11.8   -11.8
-40 6.628047    0.09141247  6.448881    6.807212    0.88    1.2 1.2
-40 6.549523    0.10354037  6.346588    6.752459    0.88    14.21   14.21
-20 7.734327    0.1245396   7.490234    7.97842 -0.72   -11.8   -11.8
-20 7.66098 0.07946067  7.50524 7.81672 -0.72   1.2 1.2
-20 7.587578    0.09873247  7.394065    7.78109 -0.72   14.21   14.21
-20 7.233594    0.12125087  6.995947    7.471241    0.08    -11.8   -11.8
-20 7.14145 0.07712451  6.990289    7.292611    0.08    1.2 1.2
-20 7.049235    0.09753204  6.858076    7.240395    0.08    14.21   14.21
-20 6.732862    0.12719752  6.483559    6.982164    0.88    -11.8   -11.8
-20 6.62192 0.08092438  6.463311    6.780529    0.88    1.2 1.2
-20 6.510893    0.09886195  6.317127    6.704659    0.88    14.21   14.21
0   7.754282    0.12270229  7.51379 7.994774    -0.72   -11.8   -11.8
0   7.699504    0.07795718  7.546711    7.852297    -0.72   1.2 1.2
0   7.644684    0.09788202  7.452839    7.836529    -0.72   14.21   14.21
0   7.256748    0.11945803  7.022614    7.490881    0.08    -11.8   -11.8
0   7.157649    0.07581817  7.009048    7.30625 0.08    1.2 1.2
0   7.058473    0.09699662  6.868364    7.248583    0.08    14.21   14.21
0   6.759214    0.12230994  6.519491    6.998937    0.88    -11.8   -11.8
0   6.615793    0.07776822  6.46337 6.768216    0.88    1.2 1.2
0   6.472263    0.09786839  6.280444    6.664081    0.88    14.21   14.21
20  7.774237    0.13150632  7.516489    8.031985    -0.72   -11.8   -11.8
20  7.738028    0.08370522  7.573969    7.902087    -0.72   1.2 1.2
20  7.701791    0.10012984  7.50554 7.898042    -0.72   14.21   14.21
20  7.279901    0.12349431  7.037857    7.521946    0.08    -11.8   -11.8
20  7.173847    0.07874583  7.019508    7.328186    0.08    1.2 1.2
20  7.067712    0.09837884  6.874893    7.260531    0.08    14.21   14.21
20  6.785566    0.12917422  6.532389    7.038743    0.88    -11.8   -11.8
20  6.609667    0.08278684  6.447408    6.771926    0.88    1.2 1.2
20  6.433632    0.10066887  6.236325    6.63094 0.88    14.21   14.21
40  7.794192    0.14907813  7.502005    8.08638 -0.72   -11.8   -11.8
40  7.776552    0.09540296  7.589565    7.963538    -0.72   1.2 1.2
40  7.758897    0.10527763  7.552557    7.965238    -0.72   14.21   14.21
40  7.303055    0.13282939  7.042714    7.563396    0.08    -11.8   -11.8
40  7.190046    0.08547351  7.022521    7.357571    0.08    1.2 1.2
40  7.07695 0.10160047  6.877816    7.276083    0.08    14.21   14.21
40  6.811918    0.14614369  6.525481    7.098354    0.88    -11.8   -11.8
40  6.60354 0.09468922  6.417953    6.789128    0.88    1.2 1.2
40  6.395002    0.10696579  6.185353    6.604651    0.88    14.21   14.21
60  7.814148    0.1727628   7.475539    8.152756    -0.72   -11.8   -11.8
60  7.815075    0.11118814  7.597151    8.033   -0.72   1.2 1.2
60  7.816004    0.11292953  7.594666    8.037342    -0.72   14.21   14.21
60  7.326209    0.14645349  7.039165    7.613252    0.08    -11.8   -11.8
60  7.206244    0.09519896  7.019658    7.392831    0.08    1.2 1.2
60  7.086188    0.10649468  6.877462    7.294914    0.08    14.21   14.21
60  6.83827 0.17022257  6.50464 7.1719  0.88    -11.8   -11.8
60  6.597414    0.11128819  6.379293    6.815534    0.88    1.2 1.2
60  6.356372    0.11619209  6.12864 6.584104    0.88    14.21   14.21
```

The following codes produces a colored plot:

```
x$GDP <- x$facet
GDP.labs <- c("-1 SD GDP","Mean GDP","+1 SD GDP")
names(GDP.labs) <- c("-11.8","1.2","14.21")

# The palette with grey:
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")


    ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = predicted, color=group)) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(y = NULL, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, 
                                       color = NULL, fill=group),
                alpha = .05) +

    facet_grid(~GDP, labeller=labeller(GDP=GDP.labs)) +

    labs(
            colour = "Perceived Poverty",
            x = "Age (Group Mean Centered)",
            y = "Life Satisfaction",
            title = "Three-Way Interaction Between Age, Perceived Poverty, and GDP"
            )
```

The following codes gave me the error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 0 provided.

```
    ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = predicted, color=group)) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(y = NULL, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, 
                                       color = NULL, fill=group),
                alpha = .05) +

    facet_grid(~GDP, labeller=labeller(GDP=GDP.labs)) +

    labs(
            colour = "Perceived Poverty",
            x = "Age (Group Mean Centered)",
            y = "Life Satisfaction",
            title = "Three-Way Interaction Between Age, Perceived Poverty, and GDP"
            )     +
scale_color_manual(name="Perceived Poverty",labels=c("-1 SD","Mean","+1 SD"),values=c("black", "gray50", "gray80") +
scale_fill_manual(name="",labels="",values="cbPalette") 

    )
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

I'm adding the plot code I tried before moving to ggplot. I can get the black and white theme but I cannot find a way to change the facet label using plot. I can change the facet label in ggplot using GDP.labs. Any hint is much appreciated.

```
plot(x, color="bw", ci=TRUE, ci.style = "ribbon", rawdata=FALSE) +
    labs(x = "Age (Group Mean Centered)",
         y = "Subjective Well-Being",
         title = "Three-Way Interaction Between Age, Perceived Poverty, and GDP",
     linetype = "Perceived Poverty") +
     scale_linetype_manual(values = 7:9, labels = c("-1 SD", "Mean", "+1 SD"))
```

Comment: At a first glance, it seems like you've forgotten a closing parenthesis `)` after `scale_color_manual`

Comment: Have you tried to set the b/w options? https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_plotcustomize.html

Comment: The color="bw" option worked but I cannot find a way to change the facet label. That's why I used ggplot and added GDP.labs in the codes above. Here's the plot code. plot(x, color="bw", ci=TRUE, ci.style = "ribbon", rawdata=FALSE) +
        labs(x = "Age (Group Mean Centered)",
             y = "Subjective Well-Being",
             title = "Three-Way Interaction Between Age, Perceived Poverty, and GDP",
   linetype = "Perceived Poverty") +
   scale_linetype_manual(values = 7:9, labels = c("-1 SD", "Mean", "+1 SD"))

Comment: Try removing the quotes from ```cbPalette``` in the line with ```scale_fill_manual(name="",labels="",values="cbPalette")```. cbPalette is an ```object```, and the quotes make that entry a ```string```.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to values=cbPalette. Same error. Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 0 provided.